# Provide WebView with Url to Asset

Tags: uno-platform

In [my Uno UWP project](https://github.com/baskren/Uno.Webview.Navigate), I can view an html Asset file (w/ `Content` **BuildAction**), stored in my shared project, using the following:

```cs
   var myAssetUri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/Html/index.html");
   myWebView.Navigate(myAssetUri);
```

However, this does not work with Android or WASM (not yet tried on other platforms).  On WASM, I get a blank page.  On Android, I get a page with the message:

> The webpage at **ms-appx-web:///Assets/Html/index.html** could not be loaded because:
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

When I look at the package folders for both platforms, I do find my html file:

- WASM: bin/Debug/netstardard2.0/dist/package_.../Assets/Html/index.html
- Android: (unziping my app's apk) assets/Html/index.html

so, I am guessing I'm not doing something right ... but I don't know what that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is simple: WebView not implemented yet on Wasm nor Skia.

Comment: That applies to WASM, but the question also asks about Android.

Comment: Thanks Carl.  That confirms that I was not misinterpreting what I saw when looking at the Uno source. For my edification, what's going on in Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution after hours investing!!

For you proyect write this line:

var myAssetUri = new Uri("file:///android_asset/Assets/Assets/Html/index.html");

This work 100%

Comment: Thanks for sharing.   Had not thought about that approach.  I needed my view to be embedded (as opposed to launching the web browser), support javascript communication back to the application, and I needed to get WebAsm working as well.  So I ended up writing my own webview.  There are some limitations in the webasm implementation (because of CORS) but it meets all of my goals.